# MongoDB code doesn't want to speak to MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mean-stack

I have been messing around with some code for a while now just trying to learn MEAN Stack, but I am constantly getting stuck at the same point on two separate computers.  I am fallowing a tutorial Youtube and am using the usual, NodeJS, Express, MongoDB, basically everything in that MEAN acronym.  I fly up to the point where I am ready to make the connection with the database (so I do perform the NPM init, perform the install for express, Mongodb (I believe MongoJS was also installed and saved as well) and ejs then I go to run the app only to get a set of brackets [] on the screen and nothing else.  There is content in the database. I am using both a locally installed version of Mongo and MongoAtlas online and both produce the same results. About the only issue I do know that comes up is that, if I try to check the version of Mongo or run it in the command line, it acts like it’s not there but it is running as a service.  I have two version of this that both have the same problem. I have included the code below. It should be noted only one computer with MongoCompass will actually access MongoAtlas at all. This would suggest a firewall issue which I have no control over on one of my machines, but my app should still have access to the local databases.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
//import mongojs from 'mongojs';
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?snappy=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb', ['test']);

router.get('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
    db.tasks.find(function(err, tasks){
        if(err){
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(tasks);
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: is mongod server installed and running in your machine, let me know which OS you are using?

Answer (score 0):

The only one reason why you get only `[]` it's because you heve no data in that collection. So, you have to add new data to that collection and your result will not like `[]` but there's your data.

To add your data, **you can try to create your `create` tasks route**.

You can use this code below you create your `create` task route.

```js
router.post('/tasks', function(req, res, next){
  db.tasks.save(req.body, function(err, tasks){
      if(err)  return res.status(400).send(err);
      res.status(201).send(tasks);
  });
});
```

Make sure your `req.body` is not undefined. If it's `undefined`, please add `body-parser` like this code below:

```js
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Now, you can try to add data using postman and call your `tasks` routes with `post` method and don't forget to add your data in `body`.

After you create some data, now you can try again to call your get `tasks` routes and then you will see your `tasks` result.

I hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check whether the mongod server is installed or not in your machine.

if you are using ubuntu hit the below command:-

```
sudo service mongod status
```

If not running then, follow the below steps and give a fresh start:-

1)Install mongodb server

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4

echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

2)Now start the service of MongoDB via command:-

```
sudo service mongod start
```

3)I never use mongojs for making connection with mongob, give a try to mongodb module

```
npm i mongodb
```

4)Make a connection with DB as follows:-

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const assert = require('assert');

// Connection URL
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017';

// Database Name
const dbName = 'myproject';

// Use connect method to connect to the server
MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, client) {
  assert.equal(null, err);
  console.log("Connected successfully to server");

  const db = client.db(dbName);
   findDocuments(db, function() {
  client.close();
});
    });



const findDocuments = function(db, callback) {
  // Get the documents collection
  const collection = db.collection('documents');
  // Find some documents
  collection.find({}).toArray(function(err, docs) {
    assert.equal(err, null);
    console.log("Found the following records");
    console.log(docs)
    callback(docs);
  });
}
```

Hope this will help you to understand MongoDB connection.

OR you can also do the same with the famous ORM with rich functionality available i.e [**mongoose**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose)